# Compiling a file and adding to a "library path"

Tags: compiling

First, I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I obtained the following directions from a CFD website:

> "Hey Alex,
>
> I just had the same problem as you did, but a friend of mine found a
>   fix. It is likely that salome forgot to update a dependency in the new
>   version (8.4.0), libjasper.so.1 in fact. You can download it from:
>   http://ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/#download , where you should download
>   jasPer 1.900.22 (the later ones have a different system). If you then
>   compile it and add the generated libjasper.so.1 to the path it works
>   like a charm ;)
>
> hopefully this is enough to fix the problem, but it would be better if
>   salome added the dependency in the next update or so. Good luck!"

I am having the same problem and would like detailed instructions on how to implement the above suggestion. I have never complied on Linux, Ubuntu, etc.

In addition to compiling, I have to add to a "library" and that is not explained in other tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: The `make install` step usually does add the library to the usual paths. There's no adding "to" a library.

Comment: FWIW I've been [installing jasper for use with digikam](https://alicious.com/compiling-jasper/) and made a blog post, someone can digest it here if they wish. They don't use make but use cmake now and the compilation is a bit involved. There are bash commands listed there. I'll make an answer here if I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the "docs" directory, there's a file called "jasper.pdf". In serction 2.4.1 there are instructions for building and installing on Linux:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The last command (`sudo make install`) should copy the `libjasper.so` to the appropriate directory. If it doesn't, just manually copy it to `/usr/lib`:

```
$ sudo cp `find ./ -name 'libjasper.so'` /usr/lib/
```

**BTW:** You're probably better off asking such questions (about building software) in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Mostly worked like a charm. The only thing I can add is that the library line should have the file: 'libjasper.so.1' for some of the menus in Salome to be fixed.